# PDO Invalid Parameter

Tags: php, pdo

Before I begin, I know there are other questions just like this, but I couldn't derive a solution from any of those. My code was working fine until I deleted it accidentally, and then had to remake it.

```
$sql    = "INSERT INTO inquiries (name, email, phone, date, message, event-type, guests, event-budget) VALUES (:name, :email, :phone, :date, :message, :event-type, :guests, :event-budget)";
$stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute(array( ':name' => $_POST['name'],
                                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                                ':phone' => $_POST['phone'],
                                ':date' => $_POST['date'],
                                ':message' => $_POST['message'],
                                ':event-type' => $_POST['event-type'],
                                ':guests' => $_POST['guests'],
                                ':event-budget' => $_POST['event-budget']
                               ));
if($result) {
    $tpl->define("alert", "<div class='col-md-12'><div class='alert-success' style='margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;'><h3><img src='http://criesvals-mbp.home:5757/_zip/_templates/_front/Refresh/multi-page/assets/images/head_img1.png' alt='' class='pull-left small_design_left'>Your Appointment Has Been Submitted<img src='http://criesvals-mbp.home:5757/_zip/_templates/_front/Refresh/multi-page/assets/images/head_img1.png' alt='' class='pull-right small_design_right'></h3></div></div>");
    $tpl->define('hide', 'style="display: none;"');
} else {
    $tpl->define("alert", "<div class='col-md-12'><div class='alert-failure' style='margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;'><h3><img src='http://criesvals-mbp.home:5757/_zip/_templates/_front/Refresh/multi-page/assets/images/head_img1.png' alt='' class='pull-left small_design_left'>There was an error submitting your appointment. Please try again later.</h3><img src='http://criesvals-mbp.home:5757/_zip/_templates/_front/Refresh/multi-page/assets/images/head_img1.png' alt='' class='pull-right small_design_right'></div>");
    $tpl->define('hide', 'style="display: none;"');
}
```

Comment: Check if all POST are set before binding

Comment: @Mihai I just double checked, and they're all indeed set. I also have if statements checking if they're "isset" & "!empty".

Comment: try to change parameter names with dashes `:event-type` to no-dashes names `:eventType` etc...

Comment: @KimAlexander that worked, but now I have a syntax error in my query. Any idea as to what it can be?

Comment: `message, "event-type", guests,` etc...  that is just bad habit to name columns with dashes... maybe it is much easier for you and much better for future to rename columns...

Comment: @Mihai I agree it's surely related, but how could it be a duplicate if the OP does not know where the error comes from ?

Comment: @KimAlexander Thanks so much for your help. I would appreciate you submit an answer so you can get the points you deserve.

Comment: It is duplicated because it is the same problem.What has knowing or not knowing about the problem has to do with being a duplicate?If he doesnt know its not a duplicate but as soon as he knows it becomes a duplicate?A bit of logic,please.And for the record,I upvoted the question.

Comment: Rather than posting a screenshot of the error, please put it into the question as plaintext so that anyone else Googling to find that text can find this question.

Comment: MySQL is interpreting two of your columns as "column_1 **MINUS** column_2"

Comment: Mihai, I'm glad that you feel concerned about my logic. Still, I don't see how the question "How can I handle PDOException Invalid parameter number" is a duplicate of "Which characters are valid for PDO placeholders". The answer to the second one induce the answer to the first, and your link indeed is very useful. But they're not the same. Anyway I was not picking a fight, I was questionning the use of "duplicate" term to point out that this question can be helpful.

Comment: @slaur4 I agree with you; both questions are related but they definitely aren't duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change parameter names with dashes `:event-type` to no-dashes names `:eventType` etc...

and probably `message, "event-type", guests, ...` etc

you are very welcome! :-)

Comment: The column names need to be wrapped in ticks `\`` - but no dashes would fix it altogether AND for the column names.